# different version of jquery conflict in apostrophecms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm using different versions of jquery in my project, there is a conflict between apostrophecms's inbuilt jquery 3 and the jquery 1.12.4 which I'm using for a carousel to work, The conflict is causing the admin functionalities not working in the apostrophecms, can anyone help.

Comment: found the temporary fix just have to change the when option like this
      self.scripts.push({ name: 'modules/jquery', when: 'anon' });
this will load the jquery1.12.4 in the user end only not in the admin end.
the carousel looks awful in the admin end but will work fine in the user end, still need to find a permanent fix.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to downgrade to jQuery 1.x is to remove this line from your project-level `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js` file:

`jQuery: 3`

However, bear in mind that jQuery 2.x and 3.x have been out for several years now and you should do what you can to migrate away from any jQuery code too old to run on them.

Answer (score 1):

To change the version of JQuery within Apostrophecms I have commented built-in JQuery version JQuery: 3 and then added updated version of jQuery through scripts.

that resolved JQuery conflict issue for me.Even though if extra JQuery Plugins also work with this solution if you want to add.

path: modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js

```
module.exports = {
  //jQuery: 3,
  scripts: [
    {
      name: 'modules/mytheme/js/jquery-3.1.1.min'
    }
  ]

};
```

My theme index file changes.

Path : modules/mytheme/index.js

```
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // loads from public/css bootstrap modules
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'bootstrap.min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'animate.min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'roboto-regular/styles.css', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'roboto-light/styles.css', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'site');

    // loads from public/js bootstrap modules
    self.pushAsset('script', 'popper', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'bootstrap.min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'jquery.appear', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'jquery.matchHeight-min', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'functions', { when: 'always' });
    self.pushAsset('script', 'site', { when: 'always' });
  }
};
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)? Which carousel do you use?

Comment: The problem got fixed, I just needed to remove both inbuilt jquery 3 and the one I'm using 1.12.4 for the carousel, in apostrophecms, the apostrophe cms, automatically degrade the jquery plugin to 1.xx version. So My problem is fixed cause of that.

Comment: Great that you figured it out!

Comment: I got help from apostrophecms gitter group :)